# How can i set Capabilities to already existing driver instance

Tags: java, selenium

I have one ChromeDriver instance and i want to add Capabilities to it. How can i add capabilities to an existing driver(ChromeDriver) instance.

Below is the driver instance.

```
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
```

And i want to add below Capability to existing instance of brower ie above one.

```
    String userAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.1; Trident/4.0; GTB7.4; InfoPath.2; SV1; .NET CLR 3.3.69573; WOW64; en-US)";
    ChromeOptions co = new ChromeOptions();
    co.addArguments("user-agent=" + userAgent);
    DesiredCapabilities cap = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
    cap.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY , co);
```

Comment: Create your instance as WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(cap);

Comment: Hi Govind, did you manage to ever get this working? I have the need to do this as I want to pass different wav files for the driver to use throughout a test.